# CVS: show files that are locally changed

Tags: cvs

Is there any simple way to show only the files in my repository that have been locally added, removed, or modified? I know that I can type "cvs stat" and look through the list of files, but that is tedious and error-prone. I am wondering if there is an easier way. I am using CVS 1.11.17, in case that matters.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

A 'dummy' update will give you this information.

```
cvs -qn update
```

A short description of the used options:

```
-q      Cause CVS to be somewhat quiet.
-n      Do not execute anything that will change the disk.
```

Comment: why not use `diff` ?

Answer (score 25):

You can get a short listing of differences using the cvs `diff` command:

```
cvs -q diff --brief
```

Answer (score 4):

Pipe it to `grep`!

```
cvs -Q status | grep -i locally
```

Comment: I tried that, and I didn't really like it. I would like to see the path for the changed files, and not just the filenames. I tried cvs stat 2>/dev/null |grep Local -B1 -A4 |grep -vE "^$" and it was a little better, but kind of messy and quirky.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use:

```
cvs -Q status | grep -A 4 Locally | egrep -v '^\-\-|^   Working|^   Commit|^$' | awk '{print $2 " " $4}' | sed -e 's/\<Locally\>//;s/revision: \CVS-REPOSITORY-PATH/\t\t/'
```

Output:

```
pin_stages.ref 
            tests/unit/ccsn/pin_stages/pin_stages.ref,v
pin_stages_func.ref 
            tests/unit/ccsn/pin_stages_func/pin_stages_func.ref,v
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is nmake-perl script list modified files, it is based on aforesaid cvs update -qn:

```
DIRS=\
  c:\project1\
  c:\project2

all: $(DIRS)
  !cd $? & cvs -qn update | perl -ne "s!\/!\\!g;print '$?\\'.qq($$1) if /^M (.*)/s;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a CVS Update
Files prepended with M are modified files.

Example:

```
CVS Update
cvsntsrv server: Updating dat/idv
M dat/idv/conduct.idv  = Modified
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to commonly mentioned `cvs update -qn`, you can go for `cvs release` command. But this one is interactive and asks for confirmation at the end of the output (so you just need to abort it!). Normal output:

```
> cvs release .
...
U some/updated/file
M some/modified/file
...
You have [1] altered files in this repository.
Are you sure you want to release directory `.': n
** `release' aborted by user choice.
>
```

After question `Are you sure you want to release directory '.':` you put something different than `y` or `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following command to get the list of files you modified locally

cvs -qn update | grep "M " | awk '{print $2}'